# Should I use hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, paired-comparisons

I have eight comparisons, each with a pair of samples where each sample contains 15 data points. The numbers shown are seconds.

The question is, with the following ranges of each one, would it be OK to use an hypothesis testing (for means) to show that there is a statistical difference, even when it is kind of obvious that results are different?

All of the points in each comparison are like this picked pairs:

1) 397 vs 4612

2) 4621 vs 0.10

3) 0.10 vs 4.62

4) 0.19 vs 4.99

5) 1.78 vs 9.37

6) 21.34 vs 44.83

7) 125.26 vs 72.61

8) 82.83 vs 66.95

Variability for each sample is never higher or lower than 1 second, for example, the other 14 samples for comparison 8) are on a range of 81-83 vs 65-67.

Then, for example, in comparison number 8, would it be necessary to perform an hypothesis testing to say that results are different, and that the first sample comes from a population with higher values? if it is not necessary, would it make any harm to perform it anyway and support a conclusion with the hypothesis testing result?

Thanks a lot, I am sorry if this is very basic question and I am really confused about it.

Comment: When deciding whether there is an "obvious" difference you need to take the variability into account. For example, 397 is obviously different to 4612 only if the underlying variability is small compared to their difference.

Comment: There is not enough detail in your question for me to understand its nature confidently, and there are typographical issues that obscure the data. Are any of the numbers you have given negative? (Some have hyphens and some have em rules.) Are the numbers you give the means of 15 datapoints, or have you shown only 8 of your 15 pairs of datapoints? What sort of things are the numbers measures of?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, very useful to note important details. The points I show are a pair I picked from each of the 8 comparisons. Each comparison has 15 pairs, and variability among them is never higher than 1, for example, for the last one the other 14 points are between 81-83, and the pair has other 14 points in a range of 65-70, it is the same for all of the 8 examples.